# How to update a pre-filled input field with a new value in React

Tags: reactjs, input

I have a todo app where if you hit search, an API will return todos from the DB, and display them in a table in the UI. An 'edit' button also gets displayed with each todo. When you click that edit button, a modal pops up with input fields that are pre-filled with the info from the DB as seen below

[I can't embed pictures yet so you'll have to click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEypW.png)

I can't seem to figure out how to handle the change in the input field in this case. I know how to handle an input field change on the 'create todo' page because I have the state of each input field set to an empty string which then gets written over by a handle change function like:

```
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  }
```

This obviously works for creating the todos because every input field value is an empty string until I enter something into the input field.

However, for the pre-filled input field, I don't know what to set the value to. If I set it to props.searchResults.todoName (just as an example) I can't change what's in the input field. The UI won't let me delete or input anything. So instead, I have the search results values set as a 'defaultValue for each input field so that it's at least pre-filling the field, and I can still enter something new in. I just don't know how to save/update that value to whatever I enter in. Please help a newbie out!

Answer (score 1):

On your form, you just add the default value: `defaultValue={this.state.todoName}` also make sure the `name={this.state.todoName}` matches the state value. This will pre-populate your input with your existing value, and whenever there's a change in the input it will update it accordingly.

Comment: So the default value is currently set to `props.seachResult.todoName` because that is the value that is being sent back from the DB. It's pre-populating the info just fine, I just can't figure out how to update it lol. As for the name portion, I'm not sure I follow your train of thought. Don't I still need an onChange handler?

Comment: That means you are handling the input from the child component. In that case the `onChange` function must be passed as a prop to the child component so every time you update the input the `onChange` function is updating the value in the Parent component. Maybe update the question and include more relevant code, like the Parent component, as well as the child component, and that will be useful.